# Hack 'minted' definition with NewTCBListing und RenewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: listings, environments, minted, definition, org-mode

A colleague and myself are trying to *hack* the `minted` environment by assigning the original meaning to `oldminted` using `\NewEnvironmentCopy` and then use this saved version in a redefinition of minted with extra arguments with `\RenewDocumentEnvironment`. Unfortunatley, it is not working right now.

We know there are straight LaTeX possibilities to edit the layout of `minted`, e.g. with `tcolorbox` etc. The motivation behind this hack is to fool another markup language, org-mode, from which we export to PDF through LaTeX, that it "assumes" it uses the normal `minted` environment, so we can customise the renewed `minted` environment to our needs in the backend and afterwards are able to simply use regular `#+begin_src` blocks in different documents withour further customisation on a per-file/session/folder basis.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% With the following lines uncommented, its not working
% \NewEnvironmentCopy{oldminted}{minted}
% \RenewDocumentEnvironment{minted}{O{}m}{\begin{oldminted}[#1]{#2}}{\end{oldminted}}

\author{Jane Doe}
\date{\today}
\title{testfile}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[]{latex}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2ex}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Running `latexmk -f -lualatex -shell-escape -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex` gives the following error-message:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> file.tex
              
! Emergency stop.
<*> file.tex
```

We guess it might has something to do with the "renaming", but couldn't figure it out so far. Since `\NewEnvironmentCopy` is really new, it might be lacking a comprehensive documentation, or I haven't found it up to this point.

---

**Edit**

The real use-case is more complex. We need an elaborated environment for highlighting source code created with `\NewTCBListing` of the `tcolorbox` package.

The idea behind this workaround is, that one can use regular **org-mode** source blocks, like:

```
#+begin_src latex
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
#+end_src
```

with all the advantages of literate programming in org-mode (like tangling, running the code, print the results) and at the same time print the source code blocks in an elaborated style if exported to pdf through latex.

Here is a MWE with a simplified `\NewTCBListing`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\parindent=0pt
\NewTCBListing{org-src-block}{om}{%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#2}

\begin{document}

A block \LaTeX Code:

\begin{minted}[]{latex}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2ex}
\end{minted}

A block \texttt{Bash} Code:

\begin{minted}[,linenos=true]{bash}
for file in array; do
    cp $file -t /home/ && echo "done"
done
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Since altering orgs own export routine is very complicated, @egreg answer in redefining `minted` through `\RenewTCBListing` seems to be the solution! My own approach with redefining `minted` otherwise was faulty from the beginning, since its used by `tcolorbox` itself.

Moreover, I don't understand how its possible to redefine an environment with tcb which was originally defined in another package... Just for the case of understanding I appreciate any hint how this is possible.

Comment: you can not use verbatim environments such as minted in the arguments of other commands,

Comment: Hmm. That's very disappointing. So there's no way to 'create' an env called minted with enhanced properties of the original `minted`?

Comment: of course there is always a way, the author of the minted package does not have uniquely magical properties that allows him to define an environment of that name, but you can not expect standard declarations to work, once you start verbatim normal rules do not apply so you need magic to spot the final `\end{,,,}` to restore things, minted or the underllying fancyverb packages have special declaration  forms or (depending on what you want tio do) you could not declare a new env but use the latex environment hooks to add new features.

Comment: why don't you use \setminted to set options?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as mentioned in my comment to egregs answer the real use case is more complex than just using `minted` (for which `setminted` would be a real possibility). I'll update the question ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

After seeing your edit, the comment is “D'oh!”.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setminted{numbersep=18pt}

\RenewTCBListing{minted}{O{}m}{%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#2,
  minted options={#1},
}

\begin{document}

A block \LaTeX Code:

\begin{minted}{latex}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2ex}
\end{minted}

A block \texttt{Bash} Code:

\begin{minted}[linenos]{bash}
for file in array; do
    cp $file -t /home/ && echo "done"
done
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Just redefine `minted`, that's so simple!

[image]

#### Original answer

Not sure how you want to redefine `minted`, but the following works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldminted}{minted}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{minted}{}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment\begin{oldminted}%
}{\end{oldminted}}

\author{Jane Doe}
\date{\today}
\title{testfile}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[]{latex}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2ex}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The parsing of arguments should be left to `\begin{oldminted}`, so `\begin{oldminted}` has to be the last item in the “begin” part. And `\VerbatimEnvironment` the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it out ASAP. Furthermore, it might help if I update the question with some more specific information's, since the simple use of `minted` and `oldminted` ist just an example. The real use case is more complex. At the moment, I've no access to my computer, thus, I'll come back to this later.

Comment: @lukeflo See edited answer. The solution was much easier than expected.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's great! But how is it possible to redefine an environment with tcb which was not initially defined by tcb??

Comment: @lukeflo Where's the problem? `\RenewTCBListing(foo)` ignores any previous definition of `foo`.

Comment: Yes, but as you mentioned, tcb uses `minted` itself in the backend while it redefines it through `\RenewTCBListing`. To me that seems like a conflict. But maybe my Latex knowledge/understanding is just too small... :D

Comment: @lukeflo I removed that comment after realizing that actually `minted` is not used,.

Comment: Ah, didn't saw that you removed the comment. Your solution works *like a charm*! Nowit is possible to export org-mode source blocks to the tcblisting environment without giving up on any org-specific literate programming skills. And further options can be added to any src block with an additional `#+attr_latex: :options <fill in some options>` line! GREAT